# Obtaining probability distribution from sns.distplot in Python

Tags: python

I have some raw data that I used from an excel sheet and I used sns.displot that shows the kde distribution as well as the histogram. How can I extract the kde distribution from sns.displot? Is there a way I can compute only the probability distribution from raw data that is not necessarily normally distributed or any common distribution such as Bernoulli etc.? I want to be able to then use the probability distribution to do further studies... Here is the code and a picture from the code. The data I obtained from an excel file that I had python read from.

```
Plot = sns.distplot(data,
              bins='auto',
              kde=True,
              color='red',
              hist_kws={"linewidth": 15,'alpha':1,'color':"blue"})
```

[Image of histogram and kde distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG6gA.png)